# sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 20 supplied

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, tkinter

I am currently having this issue with sqlite3. I am wanting to select the 'Password' from the 'Users' table on the condition that the email which the user has inputted is in the 'Users' Table. I have the query `c.execute('SELECT Password FROM Users WHERE Email = (?)',(str(email)))` which is where the error `sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 20 supplied.` is occuring.

The Users table has the columns Password and Email.

Here is the function in which this query is located:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox as ms
from tkinter import ttk
import sqlite3
from PIL import Image,ImageTk
import datetime
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import smtplib

global time 
time = datetime.datetime.now()


# make database and users (if not exists already) table at programme start up
with sqlite3.connect('Gym.db') as db:
    c = db.cursor()

c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Users (UserID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,FirstName TEXT ,LastName TEXT ,Gender TEXT,Email TEXT NOT NULL,Phone TEXT NOT NULL,Username TEXT NOT NULL,Password TEXT NOT NULL);')
c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Staff (StaffID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Role TEXT NOT NULL, Name TEXT);')
c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Gym (GymID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Location TEXT);')
c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Class (ClassID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, ClassType TEXT, Location TEXT, UserID INTEGER, Staff TEXT, StaffID INTEGER, Time TEXT, FOREIGN KEY (UserID) REFERENCES Users(UserID), FOREIGN KEY (StaffID) REFERENCES Staff (StaffID));')
db.commit()
db.close()

class main:
    def __init__(self,master):


        self.master = master

        self.verify_email = StringVar()
        self.n_verify_email = StringVar()

    def forgot_password_email(self):

            email = self.n_verify_email.get()

            with sqlite3.connect('Gym.db') as db:
                c = db.cursor()

            c.execute('SELECT Email FROM Users')

            result = c.fetchall()
            for row in result:
                r = row[0]

            c.execute('SELECT Password FROM Users WHERE Email = (?)',(str(email)))

            result2 = c.fetchall()
            for row in result2:
                r2 = row[0]

            db.commit()
            db.close()

root = Tk()
root.title("Gym Membership System")
root.iconbitmap(r'Gymicon.ico')
main(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You seem to have posted more code than what would be reasonable for your issue. Please read [ask] and how to make a [mre]; providing a MRE helps users answer your question and future users relate to your issue.

Comment: Should be `(str(email),)` as it expects a tuple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make you're (str(email)) make a tuple since at the time of parsing the query it supposed to be a tuple. So just make it like this (str(email), ) and it should work fine